# Access BitLocker drive from within .NET C# Application?

Tags: .net-framework, bitlocker, c#

Can I open a password protected drive just from withing my .NET C# app?
I need to unlock & access files from app, but not visible from Windows Explorer.

I need some encrypted app only virtual file system, not obsessed with BitLocker

Comment: Just to confirm, are you trying to unlock the drive from within your app?

Comment: I need to unlock & access files from app, but not visible from Windows Explorer.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to make the unlock only visible to your app because you'll need to mount the volume which would give it a drive letter... it can be done as https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/26c44d82-7aa3-4d18-a963-b86eb617a609/unlock-bit-locker-programmatically?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: I need some encrypted app only virtual file system, not obsessed with BitLocker